# Make overflow-x visible on hover while overflow-y is scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this issue that I couldn't find a solution for, I want to make a scroll list with `overflow-y` set to `scroll` and have `overflow-x` set to `visible` on hover.

When I try to do that it doesn't work because the browser cannot have these be different, so setting `overflow-x` to `visible` will be changed to `auto` by the browser.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14g2sacq/) (using tailwind) to show what I'm trying to achieve, basically I want to have the functionality of the column on the right hand side be implemented into the left hand side column.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is described in the [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties):

> The visible/clip values of overflow compute to auto/hidden
> (respectively) if one of overflow-x or overflow-y is neither visible
> nor clip.

Comment: Yes but is there some kind of a workaround?

Comment: Nope, you can use `title`  to see all text, or use javascript to show text on another layer.